# USB pen drive is detected in Windows but not in Ubuntu

Tags: usb

My Sony pen drive gets detected in windows but I cannot find it on my Ubuntu.
I formatted the drive with FAT,FAT32 and NTFS but the same problem.
I went through FAQs but did not find anything helpful.
I can see
Typing lsusb gives me:

```
paru@paru-Studio-1558:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6417 Microdia Integrated Webcam
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 054c:0439 Sony Corp. 
paru@paru-Studio-1558:~$
```

Comment: Have you tried plugging it in a Windows machine after Ubuntu?

Comment: what is the output of: sudo lshw  ... you'll need to determine which part is relevant

Comment: Do you know if your drive shows up under /dev ? *Are you sure* that you have ntfs drivers installed on your system? Assuming that your thumb drive is /dev/sdb, you can enter `df -hT /dev/sdb1` at the terminal to verify the filesystem format and mount point.

Comment: Also, check out what dmesg tells you before and after you plug the drive. You can skip the boring part by filtering the output of dmesg through tail: "dmesg | tail". If everything is OK, it should write something about an added (scsi?) removable drive and give you a device node like /dev/sdX...

Comment: I have the same problem. Actually, the [stick / thumb-drive / usb-flash-drive / pen-drive] worked fine (in Ubuntu) but no longer after formatting it. However, it still works fine in Windows. Other USB-sticks work fine (on the Ubuntu machine). By 'not working' I mean it is not even detected now - i.e. not seen with terminal commands lsblk etc. Strange.

Comment: Ahhhh - "sudo lshw" picks it up: /dev/sdd1    but what does one do now?